# Method call has .class as Parameter?

Tags: java

When should we give the method call the JavaClass.class as parameter? I often see something like the following code but I dont understand it:

```
String foo(Baar bar) { ... }

foo(Baar.class)
```

Comment: That's not syntactically right. Please provide concrete/real example.

Comment: In short method taking Class< T > as argument wants info about type instead of instance of type T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can declare methods to expect arguments of type Class. Something like

```
String foo(Class<Baar> bar) { ... }
```

The way you call the method is:

```
Baar bar = new Baar();
foo(bar.getClass());
```

Or something like

```
foo(Bar.class);
```

The parameter of type class can be used by the function `foo()` for various reasons: it can instantiate an new object of the same type using

```
String foo(Class<Baar> bar) {
   Baar barInstance = bar.newInstance();
}
```

It can also use it in if-then-else block to take specific actions depending on class type.

```
String foo(Class<?> bar) {
   if (bar == Baar.class) {
     System.out.println("Baar type received.");
   }
}
```

Please note that the method signature of the function expecting a Class object must explicitly say so. Otherwise it would result in a compile time error; as in your case. In your case the function foo expects a Baar object. You cannot pass it a Baar.class reference.

Answer (score 1):

When the method expects a `Class` as argument.

For example, [`EnumSet.allOf(Class<E> elementType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf%28java.lang.Class%29) expects an enum *class* (and not an enum *instance*) as argument. So, assuming `Season` is an enum, you call it using

```
EnumSet.allOf(Season.class)
```

In your example, there is no way you can pass `Baar.class` as argument to `foo()`, because `foo()` expects a Baar *instance* as argument. So what you need is something like

```
Baar baar = new Baar();
foo(baar);
```